# Unable to display this Web Part. BCS SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, bcs

I am trying to get data form SqlServer2008 in SP2010 with the hep of BCS.
I have created External List Successfully,but when I go to my Site I get following error:
Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.
I have tried second approach on this link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/10/bcs-and-external-list-learning-part1.aspx

I am not getting what is going wrong.

I am just trying to get 100 records
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, provide uls log message. Copy correlation id, go to`c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\` open most recent log file and filter records by this correlation.

Comment: Correlation ID:ecad187f-c0fb-4064-aca8-ff7d5086c092  I am new to SharePoint..
About Logs I couldn't find LOGS folder/file under "c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14"(I am not working on Server Machine)

Comment: it's hard to say something without stack trace, or error message.

Comment: Correlation ID:87ed3586-9dbe-48e1-82ef-6032ba9d73ef

Comment: 01/19/2012 19:07:22.24  w3wp.exe (0x1D14)                        0x321C Business Connectivity Services Business Data                  9f5y Medium   Calling GetMetadataObjectById with Id 2010 87ed3586-9dbe-48e1-82ef-6032ba9d73ef

Comment: 01/19/2012 19:07:22.26  w3wp.exe (0x1D14)                        0x321C Business Connectivity Services Business Data                  9f4d Unexpected 'Business Data Connectivity Service' BdcServiceApplication logging server side

Comment: MetadataObjectNotFoundException before marshalling and rethrowing on client side: IMethodInstance could not be found by id=2010 Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.MethodInstanceAccessor.GetMetadataObjectById(UInt32 methodInstanceId, Boolean performErrorCheck, Guid partitionId, DbSessionWrapper dbSessionWrapper)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.IndividuallySecurableMetadataObjectAccessor.GetNearestIndividuallySecurableMetadataObjectAncestorForMetadataObject(MetadataObjectStruct metadataObjectStruct, DbSessionWrapper dbSessionWrapper)     at

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.AccessControlledMetadataObjectAccessor.GetAccessControlEntries(MetadataOb... 87ed3586-9dbe-48e1-82ef-6032ba9d73ef 

01/19/2012 19:07:22.26* w3wp.exe (0x1D14)                        0x321C Business Connectivity Services Business Data                  9f4d Unexpected ...jectStruct metadataObjectStruct,

Comment: String settingId, Boolean fallback, DbSessionWrapper dbSessionWrapper)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.BdcServiceApplication.<>c__DisplayClass29.<Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.IBdcServiceApplication.GetAccessControlEntries>b__28()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.BdcServiceApplication.Execute[T](String operationName, UInt32 maxRunningTime, ExecuteDelegate`1 operation)  ------------------------  87ed3586-9dbe-48e1-82ef-6032ba9d73ef

Comment: I was unable to paste it in comment so I have pasted in so many comments.. Please check the log & let me know..

Answer (score 1):

I think your BCS data doesnt have the enough permission... To set the permission.. Go to Central Admin>>>Business Data Connectivity Service>>>Your BCS Connection>>> Assign permission for it using the ribbon...

Comment: Thanks Paddy I checked for permission,permissions are already set..Still error is there

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem these days and found the solution in my case ! I'm posting this hoping that it would help.

**Context:**

Sharepoint 2013 Online. External data in SQLSERVER 2012.

**Scenario:**

- via SPD, I've created an external content type, choosing SQL server for the data source.
- I've created an external list from this ECT.

**Problem:**

In my site, when I try to show my list, I get the message:

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

**Solution:**

In SPD --> External content types, I've modified my ECT connection properties and deleted the port from the server.

Hope it helps !